# How to write if statements , multiple conditions to create new column in data frame

Tags: r

I have the following script which is meant to compare values in 2 columns of a data frame and return / create a new column based on the findings (multiple conditions).

The loop runs but does not return the new column with the findings. I would call the ifelse() function to account for vectorization here however am not sure how to pass multiple conditions to it ( appears to be binary in nature)

```
for( i in nrow(LeaseDF_Region)){
  if(LeaseDF_Region$HLD_Criteria_1 == "N" && LeaseDF_Region$HLD_Criteria_2 == "N"){
LeaseDF_Region$HLD_Criteria_3 == "N"
 }else if (LeaseDF_Region$HLD_Criteria_1 == "Y" && LeaseDF_Region$HLD_Criteria_2 == "Y"){
  LeaseDF_Region$HLD_Criteria_3 == "Y"
 }else if (LeaseDF_Region$HLD_Criteria_1 == "Y" && LeaseDF_Region$HLD_Criteria_2 == "N"){
  LeaseDF_Region$HLD_Criteria_3 == "Y"
}else if(LeaseDF_Region$HLD_Criteria_1 == "N" && LeaseDF_Region$HLD_Criteria_2 == "Y"){
   LeaseDF_Region$HLD_Criteria_3 == "Y"
}
}
```

Data is just values N and Y randomized for Col 1 and 2. So I am looking to do the following ( for each row in the DF) :

- IF col 1 is an n and col 2 is an n then return n in new col 3
- IF col 1 is an n and col 2 is a y then return y in new col 3
- IF col 1 is a y and col 2 is a n then return y in new col 3
- IF col 1 is a y and col 2 is a y then return y in new col 3

Note n = no and y = yes

Comment: `nrow` returns a unique value; `i` doesn't appear anywhere in your script; this is not an exhaustive list of your code's issues... try to add a bit of your data and what exactly is your goal, it would be easier to help you.

Comment: Try this (with dplyr package) : LeaseDF_Region %>% mutate(HLD_Criteria_3 = ifelse(LeaseDF_Region$HLD_Criteria_1 == "N" &
          LeaseDF_Region$HLD_Criteria_2 == "N", "N",
ifelse(...))

Comment: Possibly `LeaseDF_Region$HLD_Criteria_3 <- ifelse(LeaseDF_Region$HLD_Criteria_1 == "N" & LeaseDF_Region$HLD_Criteria_2 == "N", "N", "Y")`? This would be much easier if you used logical variables instead of text "N"/"Y".

Comment: @cath please see above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply use data table subsetting...
first initialize a column, then assign it values based on your conditions. so here DF is my dataframe, and TEMP is the parameter I am classifying my new comlumn "control temp" with.

```
DF$Control_Temp <- NA
DF$Control_Temp[DF$TEMP <= 50 & DF$TEMP2 == -1] <- 'Y'
DF$Control_Temp[DF$TEMP > 50 & DF$TEMP <= 100 & DF$TEMP2 == -1] <- 'N'
DF$Control_Temp[DF$TEMP > 100 & DF$TEMP2 == -1 ] <- 'Y'
```

Comment: This makes complete sense. Ended up with `LeaseDF_Region$HLD_Criteria_3 <- NA
LeaseDF_Region$HLD_Criteria_3[LeaseDF_Region$HLD_Criteria_1 == "N" & LeaseDF_Region$HLD_Criteria_2 == "N"] <- "N"
LeaseDF_Region$HLD_Criteria_3[LeaseDF_Region$HLD_Criteria_1 == "Y" & LeaseDF_Region$HLD_Criteria_ == "Y"] <- "Y"
LeaseDF_Region$HLD_Criteria_3[LeaseDF_Region$HLD_Criteria_1 == "Y" & LeaseDF_Region$HLD_Criteria_2 == "N" ] <- "Y" 
LeaseDF_Region$HLD_Criteria_3[LeaseDF_Region$HLD_Criteria_1 == "N" & LeaseDF_Region$HLD_Criteria_2 == "Y" ] <- "Y"`

Answer (score 1):

Try this (with dplyr package) :

```
LeaseDF_Region %>% mutate(HLD_Criteria_3 = 
                            ifelse(LeaseDF_Region$HLD_Criteria_1 == "N" &
                                   LeaseDF_Region$HLD_Criteria_2 == "N", "N", 
                                   ifelse(LeaseDF_Region$HLD_Criteria_1 == "Y" & 
                                          LeaseDF_Region$HLD_Criteria_2 == "Y", "Y", 
                                          ifelse(...))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Jacob Odom's post, I like subscripting. I think it's a bit cleaner to set everything to "Y" and then map out the "N"s:

```
LeaseDF_Region$HLD_Criteria_3 <- "Y" # Set all values to "Y"
index_n <- `&`(
    # Map out the "N" indexes with a boolean vector
    LeaseDF_Region$HLD_Criteria_1 == "N",
    LeaseDF_Region$HLD_Criteria_2 == "N"
)
LeaseDF_Region$HLD_Criteria_3[index_n] <- "N" # Assign "N" accordingly
```

Comment: Nice use calling out `'&'` as a function call instead of an inline operator. I always know the syntax is there but keep forgetting how it can present code in a different manner.

Comment: @r2evans Thx. I think it's more expressive that way, and I like putting comments within the function call, kind of like a mini docstring. Otherwise it's like 100 lines across and I'm not sure what I'm looking at.

Comment: I was about to comment that I sometimes wish R supported the "docstring" concept. And then I realized it does, partially: literal strings in the middle of code (in most places) will serve that purpose just fine, albeit having a small effect on performance.

Comment: @r2evans Yeah I like having the docstring pop up as I'm typing, e.g. as in Python. I suppose I could look into tools like RStudio to get something similar, but I usually just use the google style notation [link](https://google.github.io/styleguide/Rguide.xml) for function descriptions and type in the function to view the source, with documentation at the top.

Comment: If something goes wrong, it would be easier to see if you initialized the variable with ``NA`` rather than ``"Y"``.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(C1 = sample(c('Y','N'), 10, replace=T), C2 = sample(c('Y','N'), 10, replace=T))

dt[, C3 := ifelse(C1 == 'Y' | C2 == 'Y', 'Y', 'N')]
```

Giving you

```
    C1 C2 C3
 1:  Y  N  Y
 2:  N  N  N
 3:  Y  Y  Y
 4:  Y  N  Y
 5:  N  N  N
 6:  N  Y  Y
 7:  N  N  N
 8:  Y  Y  Y
 9:  N  N  N
10:  N  Y  Y
```

Comment: Thanks @martin .. this makes sense.